# How to get resolved data from a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Consider the following code snippet:

```
let primise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({ x: 10 });
});

setTimeout(() => {
  // At some moment in the future (Promise is resolved)
    console.log(promise);
}, 200);
```

Now, the promise was resolved with `{ x: 10 }`. How do I access this data using the resolved promise ?

Inspecting the promise object I can see the data is available as `promise._v` but this doesn't look right. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: As always: `promise.then(console.log)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot inspect promises (at least not native promises, some userland implementations do have synchronous inspection methods available).

So - as always - use `promise.then(v => console.log(v))`. Only then you can be sure that the promise is fulfilled.

If you also want to wait 200ms, use another promise for the timeout and `Promise.all` to wait for both of them:

```
let promise = Promise.resolve({ x: 10 });

Promise.all([promise, new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200))]).then([v] => {
    // At some moment in the future (and promise is fulfilled)
    console.log(v); // {x: 10}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of a promise is so that you don't have to wait an arbitrary amount of time to determine whether the promise is resolved... you just hook into it.

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({ x: 10 });
});

...

promise.then(data => {
    // use data here...
});
```